# set value for text shadow property using DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I want to give the value for text-shadow properties one by one using DOM in javascript.
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;

```
if(conf.hasOwnProperty('vshadow')) document.getElementById('p1').style.text.hshadow = 5px;
if(conf.hasOwnProperty('hshadow')) document.getElementById('p1').style.text.vshadow = 5px;
if(conf.hasOwnProperty('blurRadius')) document.getElementById('p1').style.text.blurradius = 5px;
if(conf.hasOwnProperty('shadowColor')) document.getElementById('p1').style.text.color = red;
```

i tried the above code.but that does not work.
is there any way to do this using DOM in javascript

Comment: what kind of element is 'p1'?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if the DOM objects *hshadow, vshadow, blurradius* really do exist but the correct code should be  `document.getElementById('p').style.textShadow = "5px 5px 5px red"`

Comment: But i want to get the value for each property one by one.

Comment: Then why not get them in variables and finally set it to like `document.getElementById('p').style.textShadow = hshadow+" "+vshadow+" "+blurRadius+" "+color;`

Answer (score 0):

The text shadow syntax is:

```
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;
```

So when you want to apply particular properties, you can apply like:

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ff0000;
```

To apply through JS:

```
document.getElementById('p1').style.textShadow = "2px 2px 2px #ff0000";
```

Hope this helps.